# How to skip reader in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Is there any way to skip  the reader in a job step?

For example I would like to use a reader as a sort of "pass through", using it to pass directly the source file that I need to the processor.

Is that possible?

EDIT: I need to use the spring batch "architecture" because I need to re-use my writer. The file I need to process is not suitable to any of the spring reader, and I want only to process it. So I want to use the Reader only as a pass through for my input file.

Comment: What would you be passing through?  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: I've added some more details...

Comment: Again, what would the reader do then?  Where does it get this file from and what makes it "not suitable to any of the spring reader"?  You can't create a custom reader?

Comment: the resource is injected in the job configuration class, it's from the file system and it's a PDF file. I don't want to create a custom reader, because I will read it only once.

Comment: What prevents you from implementing a custom reader which passes the bytestream?

Comment: i was just curious about this option.